# How to import MSSQL database dump from Plesk into local MS SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, import, dump

I have a plesk account and an MS SQL database from which I got a dump through this interface they provide:

[image]

So I downloaded the dump file but it does not come as a `.txt` file but it comes without any extension and when I try to import it in my local MS SQL Server it fails always.

[image]

And when I try to open the dump file with notepad it shows weird characters(see picture below).

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: The Plesk doco says it's a ZIP file. Rename the file to have .ZIP extension and try opening it. https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/customer-guide/advanced-website-databases/exporting-and-importing-database-dumps.69538/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I extracted the file in from the ZIP, and that file is without extension having the content I've shown in the post.

Comment: I don't see any mention of restoring to a local instance in the doco, but you could try renaming to .bak (though it doesn't really matter) and restoring that file. https://support.managed.com/kb/a1788/how-to-manually-restore-an-mssql-database-in-management-studio.aspx

Comment: The only other binary format is BCP binary but there would be one file per table. So it's probably a backup file

Comment: so you mean its's not a dump. but i followed plesk instructions correctly, I don't understand

Comment: The plesk instructions appear to describe exporting a dump from plesk and importing a dump into plesk. There's nothing there about importing a dump into a local SQL Server instance. If there is, please leave a reference and I'll take a look

Comment: indead I've not yet seen that, I've been searching since yesterday, that's why I tried SO to see... but this is very not smart of them if the exported file can only be imported back to the same place. I'll keep trying...

Comment: Well it is smart of they want to keep you using their platform and not migrating on to another platform. It looks like you can connect with ODBC so you could use an ETL tool to extract data. What's the purpose of restoring the database locally? At this point we are basically just reverse engineering a Plesk dump

Comment: This article basically says it's proprietary and has a dead link https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204405004/can-i-manually-extract-files-from-backups-created-by-plesk

Comment: it's a long story but some one worked on a project and disapeared and I have to do some modifications,  so i want to have the db locally so i can work on it and then upload the new code.

Comment: I'm only guessing but I assume you'd need to make a copy in Plex and work within Plex. PS I don't even know what Plex is

Comment: haha, Plex is a webhosting platform. but i don't want to work in it as you thought..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my way using a php script found on github I had to fork it to update couple things cause it became obsolete.

I had to go this way for couple reasons:

- I didn't have admin access to the plesk server to enable remote DB access
- I wasn't able to export it into any format readable by mysql

So with the php script i could load it unto the server and run it,
The script copies an MSSQL into MySQL. Here is my [fork](https://github.com/Xsmael/mssql2mysql).

Answer (score 6):

I got it to work by extracting the dump file from the zip and renaming it with a .bak extension. Then did a Database restore in MS SQL Management Studio and selected this backup file (.bak). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I had to find another way around. was really getting sick of mssql '^^

Comment: I just did this and it was actually that simple: add extension, restore from file.  This should be the accepted answer for the current title of the question.  But I realized with the OP's explanation, during the acceptance of their own answer, that the real question is, "How can I create a MySQL DB from a MS SQL backup (which happens to be a Plesk dump)?".