# How to import Plesk SQL Server dump to my localhost

Tags: sql-server, plesk

I take 'export dump' from Plesk SQL Server.

I'm trying to import it to my localhost via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

But files look like broken or encoded. Isn't there any way to import Plesk dump into the localhost?

Comment: What kind of files are you talking about? SQL Server doesn't do "dumps" - you can either **backup** a database into a `*.bak` file (and then restore that backup file), or you can detach a SQL Server database and get it's `.mdf / .ldf / .ndf` files and re-attach those on another SQL Server instance. ....

Comment: Plesk dumps are .zip files containing .sql files. But are you sure it's Microsoft SQL Server behind Plesk? It's usually MySQL.

Comment: Since I just went through this I can say with confidence that at least with hosting providers that allow you to stand up SQL Server databases and that provide access to Plesk to manage things, Plesk dumps are .zip files that contain one single file inside, and that file has no extension but once you extract it, the next immediate step is rename it to have the extension .bak, because that's what it is, it's a SQL Server .bak file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here [How to import MSSQL database dump from Plesk into local MS SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54071639/how-to-import-mssql-database-dump-from-plesk-into-local-ms-sql-server)

Once you have the Plesk SQL Server dump .zip file on your local workstation and you've loaded it into your .zip utility, you'll see it has only one file inside the .zip.

Extract the file you find in the zip.  It has no extension.  The fact it has no extension adds some mystery to those of us doing this for the first time, because it effectively hides from us the fact that this file is a SQL Server backup file.

Rename the extensionless file as a .bak file.

Use SQL Server Management Studio's "Restore Database..." action to import the .bak file.

Set up local login to this new local database; you would typically make sure the login has dbo access to the new db.

Adjust the configuration on your local code to point at the new db.  AND DONE.